# simpleWebRTC with php backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, webrtc

I am using simpleWebRTC with xhr to implement peculiar multi-users video chat (no audio)
my main issue in short: i was unable to attach the username from php to the correct video in JS

in my quetion i will
 1. explain what i have done - and what are my current issues
 2. if my current route is impossible - then i ask for suggestions for a different course of action on my part :-) - my knowledge is in JS and PHP|

the multi-users video allows to chose a few users and see them in a one way connection.
lets say we have users A, B, C, D
user A chooses to see users B, C, D while user B for example only chooses to see users C and D .... and so on

in simpleWebRTC i thought of two courses of action
a. one room for all of the participants and then to filter them down (was unsuccessful as i was unable to attach the correct username to each video - to filter them out)
2. instead i created a room (with username - email, as id) and let each user connect to the appropriate room.

in the first part of the code i have an XHR that pulls a list of the people the user wishes to subscribe to there videos (i.e: chooses to see)

```
var remoteRoom = [];


    $.get('scripts/video/ours/musesSimpleList.php', function(msg){

            myRoom = msg.username;

            var remoteRoomArray = $.each( msg.museUsername, function(key, value){
                remoteRoom.push = value;


                return remoteRoom;
            });

            afterRoomDefined(myRoom, remoteRoomArray);
    }, 'json');
```

function afterRoomDefined(myRoom, remoteRoomArray) is called after the list of people this specific user chose to register to was retrieved from MySQl

in this function, i now try to implement the WebRTC:

```
function afterRoomDefined(myRoom, remoteRoom){


console.log('remote room name: '+ remoteRoom + ' type: '+ $.type(remoteRoom));


remoteRoom = JSON.stringify(remoteRoom);
console.log('isArray '+$.isArray(remoteRoom));

//Create our WebRTC connection
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    url:'https://signaling.simplewebrtc.com:443',
    //the element that will hold the local video
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    //the element that will hold remote videos
    //remoteVideosEl: 'remotes',
    remoteVideosEl: '',
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    media: {
            video: true,
            audio: false
        },

});


webrtc.mute();

// a peer video has been added

var i = 0;

//When it's ready and we have a room from the URL, join the call
webrtc.on('readyToCall', function(peer){

//each user first creates a room for himself - so other users could connect to
if(myRoom) webrtc.joinRoom(myRoom);

    //here a room is created for every person the user subscribed to. each person created a room with his own username (when he opened this page in his browser) - in the line above. so now i open rooms with the same names - so the users will see each other (two ways now)
    for(var b=0; b<remoteRoom.museUsername.length; b++){
        console.log('remoteRoom loop - separate values: '+ remoteRoom.museUsername[b]);
        if(remoteRoom.museUsername[b]) webrtc.joinRoom(remoteRoom.museUsername[b]);
    }
});


// a peer video has been added
webrtc.on('videoAdded', function (video, peer) {

var remotes = document.getElementById('remotes');
if (remotes) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'videoContainer'+i;

    $(container).attr('data-username', remoteRoom.museUsername[i]);
    i++;


    container.id = 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer);
    container.appendChild(video);

    // suppress contextmenu
    video.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };

    remotes.appendChild(container);

    //this is to remove the other party video - if a user only subscribed to another user - the other user is not
    //$('#remotes div:not[data-username]').css('border', 'red 5px solid');
   $('#remotes div:not[data-username]').remove();
}
i=i+1;
});

webrtc.on('videoRemoved', function (video, peer) {

var remotes = document.getElementById('remotes');
var el = document.getElementById(peer ? 'container_' + webrtc.getDomId(peer) : 'localScreenContainer');

$('#remotes div').css('border', '#F4171A 2px solid');
if (remotes && el) {
    remotes.removeChild(el);
}
});
```

That's it. and that basically works.
There are three issues though:
a. when one of the users refreshes his page (usually navigate back an forth) his own video  is added again (two videos of the same user now - one of them is frozen) to all the other users who watches him. perhaps its an issue with

```
webrtc.on('videoRemoved'...
```

b. when user A for example registers to user B... - if user C than subscribes to user A - he will see also user B
the main issue perhaps is:
c. i was never really able to attach the username to the right video under:

```
 webrtc.on('videoAdded',....
 $(container).attr('data-username', remoteRoom.museUsername[i]);...
```

in the main block code.
I used

```
 $('#remotes div:not[data-username]').remove();
```

to find all videos without username and kick (videos who were duplicated and froze+the other side of the video if user A subscribed to user B and not vice versa so user B will not see user A and so that C will not see in the above explanation) them out - but the username it self is not attached to the correct child in the right order (the moment someone refreshes the page the order scrambles....

2. am i going the right direction?
   i had a look at pubNub, xirsys, firebase and some other solutions 
   (google appengine - java knowledge required, html5Rocks, easyRTC, signalMaster (no proper explanation on how to use)- but it seems that they all require node.js  )

is my current mode of action (php and XHR) is a valid one?
if not - will one of the other solution will be relatively simple and plausible.
I started looking through too many api's and am confused by now

thank you :-)

Comment: i suspect i need a proper signaling mechanism - perhaps using firebase or pubnub for that? while using my own php as backed.... ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly what goes wrong, because you seems to face multiple issue here, including webRTC in general and DOM insertion/removal problems.

If you are seeking for webRTC solution using PubNub, you should take a look at:

https://github.com/stephenlb/webrtc-sdk

and the demo that you can try:
http://stephenlb.github.io/webrtc-sdk/

also, check out

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/building-a-webrtc-video-and-voice-chat-application/

Comment: thank you 
i managed to solve that issue - the problems that remains now are:
1. i need a signaling server - preferably using simpleWebRTC signalmaster (or something that will be compatible with simpleWebRTC) 
2. stun and turn servers
can pubNub supply something like that? :-)

Comment: @NamiNam can you post your solution?